# Hazelcast 3.11 + log4j

Tags: log4j, hazelcast

Good day, does anyone find information about log4j involving Hazelcast 3.11?
In the official website doesn't show anything about the log4j vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability is addressed in Log4j2.15.0. Hazelcast team is currently working to release fixes to add this for the versions listed above. UPDATE on December 15, 2021: IMDG 4.0.4, 4.1.7 and 4.2.3 have been released. Remaining release of Hazelcast 5.0.1 and Hazelcast Jet 4.5.2 is being worked on.

Users that explicitly use a vulnerable Log4j2 library are advised to upgrade to Log4j2.15.0 as soon as possible.

For more: [Security Advisory for "Log4Shell" CVE-2021-44228 and CVE-2021-45046](https://support.hazelcast.com/s/article/Security-Advisory-for-Log4Shell)